# Getting error while running ASP.NET Website on Local Host Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

I'm running a web application developed on ASP.NET; C# and SQL Server 2008; on Local Host on a Network.
It is showing an error 500.19 for some Permissions...
Can anyone help me out to solve this and run my website on localhost without hosting it online.....[Have a look, What's the error is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhxzK.png)

Comment: You should add the error log that will contain more information about the 500

Comment: Have a look at [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055). There some issue with your configuration file.

Comment: I have added an image please have a look and describe...

Comment: Mr. Suprabhat Biswal, I visited Microsoft Support but it didn't worked...

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue of *permissions for the directory/files for your application.*

Make sure you have given the **full permission** to the users types that will be accessing the application.

For adding/editing permissions, you can navigate to the concerned folder and right click on it, selec properties and then go to security tab wherein you can edit the permissions of existing users as well as add new users with specific permissions.

Also, if you have your application hosted on IIS, there is also an option for changing permissions which will again, open the folder for you and you will have to follow the same steps as mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Such issue occurs when, some wrong or duplicate element added in web.config file.

Verify your web.config file.

Also confirm execute version of virtual directory (32 Bit / 64 Bit)

Comment: Give the read/Write permission to NNSEnroll directory (which is your application home) with the application pool identity